# Django-rest-auth using user object

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-auth

I have a django project in which I am using a django-rest-auth to authenticate users. My settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'rest_framework',
 #following was added to allow cross domain requests
 'corsheaders',
 #following were added for ssl thing
 'djangosecure',
 'sslserver',
 #following were added for authentication
 'rest_framework.authtoken',
 'rest_auth',
 'allauth',
 'allauth.account',
 'rest_auth.registration',
 'demo',
)
```

I have two models: **Exercise** and **Rating**. I did not create a ***User*** model as it must be provided by django-rest-auth / django.contrib.auth. 
A user can give multiple ratings to a particular exercise.

My models.py look like following:

```
class Exercise(models.Model):

#Field for storing exercise type
EXERCISE_TYPE_CHOICES = (
    (1, 'Best stretch'),
    (2, 'Butterfly reverse'),
    (3, 'Squat row'),
    (4, 'Plank'),
    (5, 'Push up'),
    (6, 'Side plank'),
    (7, 'Squat'),
)
exercise_type = models.IntegerField(choices=EXERCISE_TYPE_CHOICES)

#Field for storing intensity level
INTENSITY_LEVEL_CHOICES = (
    (1, 'Really simple'),
    (2, 'Rather Simple'),
    (3, 'Simple'),
    (4, 'Okay'),
    (5, 'Difficult'),
    (6, 'Rather Difficult'),
    (7, 'Really Difficult'),
)

intensity_level = models.IntegerField(choices=INTENSITY_LEVEL_CHOICES)
#Field for storing video url for a particular exercise
video_url = models.URLField()
#Field for storing description of the exercise
description = models.CharField(max_length=500)


class Rating(models.Model):

#Field for storing exercise type
exercise = models.ForeignKey(Exercise, related_name='ratings', blank=True, null=True)
#Field for storing rating
RATING_CHOICES = (
    ('H', 'Happy'),
    ('N', 'Neutral'),
    ('S', 'Sad'),
)
value = models.CharField(max_length=1,choices=RATING_CHOICES)
```

According to the description above my ***Rating*** model should also contain *userid* as a foreign key along with *exerciseid*, right?

How can I achieve this? How can I modify my Rating model? What I will need to import?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Rating(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    # other fields
```

I think this is what you are looking for. 
[Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/) is an example that I think is related to your question

Comment: However, shouldn't it be Foreign key instead of oneTooneField?

Comment: Sorry. My bad. I read your question very quickly and thought your question was how to add a field corresponding to the user in your model.  I will modify the answer.